# JQuery- add css for each img element having a class

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.resizeImage").each(function(){
        var img = $(this); 
        var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
        var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height
       // alert("give image size ....."+width+", "+height);
        var pic_real_width, pic_real_height;
        $("<img/>").attr("src", $(img).attr("src"))
            .load(function() {
                pic_real_width = this.width;  
                pic_real_height = this.height; 

            });

        if(pic_real_width < width  ){
            //alert("display original width.sssss 103..");
            $(this).removeAttr("width");
            $(this).css("width",pic_real_width);
        }

        if( pic_real_height < height ){
            //alert("display original height ss.102..");
            $(this).removeAttr("height");
            $(this).css("height",pic_real_height);
        }
    });
});
```

in above jquery execution flow is not hitting last if conditions. I am not acquiring desired result. If I keep some alert above the two if()s then execution flow goes inside two if conditions. pl help me .
How can execute jquery statements line by line..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image loading is asynchronous, which means that the `.load` callback won't be called straight away.

Hence `pic_real_width` and `pic_real_height` are unknown at the point you try to use them.

Perhaps you should move those two conditions *into* the callback function?

Comment: Then How can I get original height and width of each img element without load. any other solution.? what I want is if image is smaller than given Height and width I dont want it to be streched , show image in original height and width.

Comment: Instead of checking the image size and removing height/width if image is smaller, why not try max-height and max-width CSS properties?
img {max-width: 100px;} will cause that the image will never be stretched and larger images will never exceed 100px width.